# Best practices to export CSV in PHP: output buffer vs temporary file

Tags: php, csv

## Best practices to export CSV in PHP: output buffer vs temporary file

### Scenario

I execute a SELECT on a database that returns any number of rows, may be few or many (one million+), those rows need to go inside a .csv file with the first row beeing header.

### Doubt

I know two ways of exporting CSV files with PHP: using output buffer `php://output` or creating a temporary file, serve it to user, than delete it.

Which way is better, knowing it may be a small file or a very big one? Consider PHP memory limit (in php.ini), request time out, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the situation.

Use an output buffer when you know the file is not ridiculously large and when it is a download that doesn't occur to often.

When you have something large, that will be downloaded a large number of times (simultaneous), writing it to a file might be better to lighten the load on your database and site.

Answer (score 2):

Using the temporary file in case you have large file is the only good option.

1. you can redirect second request(if file exist) directly to your file and let web server to serve it without executing php.
2. if client has disconnected, while download a file through api, - in most cases he will start downloading again;
3. more of that, you will got access logs on your web server, to check who and how many times access this file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd think the answer is pretty obvious: write directly to `php://output`. It's the same as `echo ..`; the output will be send to the client more or less directly. It may or may not get *buffered* for a bit, but unless you have explicit output buffering activated or your web server has a ridiculously large buffer, it'll send it right through. "Sending a file" (presumably via `readfile`) would pass the data though the same output buffer, but would be much more complicated and error prone.