# write csv in ram and output file to user [php]

Tags: php, csv

First of all, I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438318/best-practices-to-export-csv-in-php-output-buffer-vs-temporary-file), but that doesn't do the trick when if I understand it correctly.

I'm creating a csv-file with `PHP` with the following function(s).

```
 // open the file. If not existent yet, create it first
 if (!file_exists($this->filename))
 {
     touch($this->filename);
 }

 $handle = fopen($this->filename, "w+");
 if ($this->includeHeaders)
 {
     $headers = array('Company', 'Contactperson', 'Username', 'Commission', 'WinCAP Version', 'WinCAP Link', 'Contract due', 'POS Version', 'POS Link', 'Quick Select Version', 'Quick Select Link', 'Password');
     fputcsv($handle, $headers);
 }

 // mysql-stuff here

 while ($row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res))
 {
     fputcsv($handle, $row, ";", '"');
 }

 // done
 fclose($handle);
```

As you can tell, it is `TYPO3`-related, but that shouldn't bother here. However, my file is generated correctly, containing all the data I need. However, the file is created on the filesystem. That means, anyone with the link to that file, can download it.

This is what I want to prevent. I was thinking about adding a hash, but that doesn't seem to protect it well enough. So I cam up with the idea: why not just open the `save-file dialog`, after creating that file. This means, the file shouldn't be stored on the FS, right?

I read a bit about the `output-buffer`, but what would the file for the `$handle` be? PHP:\\out?

Just to clarify:
User clicks "export" -> after proccessing the data and finishing the file, show SAVE-dialog in Browser. Don't save the file on the FS.

Comment: Use `php://output` as your filename; just make sure you send the right headers to tell the browser that you're sending text/csv and not text/html as a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send the file for download and then delete it. Add this right after your code:

```
// Send correct http headers
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/csv") ;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=ChooseFilename.csv");
header("Expires: 0");

// Send file to browser
readfile($this->filename);

// delete file
unlink($this->filename);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be deleted right after displaying the download-prompt?

Comment: No, would be sent first.